# how to show a sequential flow of data in any visualization?

Tags: d3.js, cognos, tableau-api

Any visualization or chart type which is suitable to show a sequential flow data .for example an employees organisation and job location changes through time..How to show his job location and organisation tack through time[image: Test Data] in a chart.

[image: some visualization which can show things like this order]

Answer (score 0):

You've listed 3 environments that you could be using for a visualization: tableau, cognos, and d3. You really need to be more specific on where you're looking to produce the visualization.

D3 can produce just about anything you want it to. Network & graph visualizations are pretty common.

For tableau, take a look at Sankey diagrams, they may be sufficient.

Cognos: Nothing built in, but Cognos provides a framework for customizing visualizations: RAVE. They deliver a dozen or so examples, and docs on how to make your own.